# Is it possible to set preferred sample buffer size for AVCaptureOutput?

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, avaudiosession, avcaptureoutput

Say we have an `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` object that has been set up with an `AVCaptureSession` to get data samples from the device's microphone.

`captureOutput(_:didOutput:from:)` in `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` always gets called with 2048 bytes of samples. Is it possible to set a preferred sample buffer size?

A basic example:

```swift
let output = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
output.setSampleBufferDelegate(delegate, queue)
// Add output to AVCaptureSession and start the capture session once everything is set up
...

// In the delegate
public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, 
                          didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, 
                          from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    // sampleBuffer is 2048 bytes, but I want less
    let blockBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    print(CMBlockBufferGetDataLength(blockBuffer!)) // 2048
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have a look at `AVAudioSession`'s `setPreferredIOBufferDuration` method - it _might_ influence the capture session buffer size.

Comment: I tried that. It did set `ioBufferDuration` close to what I wanted, but it made no difference to the sample buffer size.

Comment: When `setPreferredIOBufferDuration` succeeds it does influence the AudioUnit buffer size. What are you trying to do? Do you need lower latency capture? If so, switch to remote io audio units.

Comment: Yes I need lower latency capture. I'll take a look at remote IO audio units as I've never heard of it before.

Comment: @VictorDurojaiye did you figure how to do it?

Comment: Not with `AVAudioSession`. As suggested, I ended up using RemoteIO Audio Units and I had more control over the buffer size, among other things.